# How to use the Lemma of Heine–Borel in order to prove the existence of an irrational number.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

After learning about the Theorem of Heine–Borel, which states that for intervals on the real line of type $[a,b]$, $\textit{every open cover has a finite subcover}$.  the lecturer gave us a task to think about, which is to prove the existence of an irrational number by using this lemma. he asked us to think about the closed interval $[0,1]$ for example, and how to build for it an open cover (which is based on the rational numbers) s.t. a finite subcover of it, which exists according to lemma, creates a contradiction. (turns out that it doesn't cover all the inteval $[0,1]$.)

do you guys have any hints for how to do that?

Comment: This question answers it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107590/heine-borel-for-rationals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possibility.  Suppose all the numbers in [0,1] are rational.  We know the rational numbers in [0,1] are countable, i.e. they can be enumerated $\{ q_1, q_2, q_3, \dots \}$.  Enclose $q_1$ in an open interval of width $1/2$, $q_2$ in an open interval of width $1/4$, $q_3$ in an open interval of width $1/8$, etc.  Since we are assuming all the numbers in [0,1] are rational, this is an open cover of [0,1], hence there is a finite subcover.  The subcover has a total width strictly less than $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \dots = 1$.  But you can't cover [0,1] with a finite set of intervals of total width less than $1$.  Contradiction.

Comment: Interesting. thanks :)

Comment: but the question is, how can u create open cover of [0,1] only by enclosing rational numbers, are you saying that u are covering all the interval [0,1] only by rationals?

Comment: By assuming every number in $[0,1]$ is rational, you prove it is not compact.  This contradiction implies there must be an irrational number.

Answer (score 1):

This does not quite answer the OP's question because it uses the existence of an irrational to show that $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is not compact.  However, the OP asked to prove existence.

Hint: $\pi-3$ is irrational and within $[0,1]$.  Let $x_n$ be the truncated $\pi-3$ (i.e., the decimal expansion of $x_n$ agrees with $\pi-3$ on the first $n$ positions and is $0$'s after that).  Observe that $x_n$ is *rational*.  Then the open intervals $(-\infty,x_n)$ cover $[0,\pi-3)$ but there is no finite subcover (requires proof).  Now, think about doing the same thing on the other side of $\pi-3$.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by the decimal expansion of $x_n$ agrees with $\pi−3$ on the first $n$ positions and is $0's$ after that

Comment: Observe that $\pi-3=0.14159265359...$.  Then $x_1=0.1$, $x_2=0.14$, $x_3=0.141$, $x_4=0.1415$ and so on.

Comment: I got it, and by doing a similar thing on the right side I get that the intervals $(b_n,\infty)$ cover $(\pi-3]$,but there is no finite subcover for them too. which means the whole interval $[0,1]$ doesn't have a finite subcover. but the problem is that none of the subcovers that I mentioned really "Includes" $\pi-3$ althoough its a point in the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: That isn't quite the problem (because $\pi-3$ isn't a rational).  The problem is that $\cup_{i=1}^k(-\infty,x_{n_i})$ where $x_{n_i}<x_{n_{i+1}}$ doesn't include the largest value, $x_{n_k}$.

Comment: yeah, and this problem means there must be an irrational number in between, right?

Comment: I think this problem is a bit strange, since you're asked to _prove the existence_ of an irrational number, yet in order to do something like what this answer does (which in my opinion is the obvious approach) you have to _know_ that $\pi - 3$ is irrational in the first place.

Comment: You're right @Arthur .  I will rethink this approach because I am using the fact that $\pi-3$ is not rational.

Comment: you are right, but I guess that the lecturer assumes that we know the difference between rational and irrational by definition, and that for example $\pi$ is irrational. so its like a fact. @Arthur

Comment: The problem is that idea uses existence to prove existence.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I know what you mean, but u don't think there is another way to prove this without assuming that we know about an irrational number in the interval?